# High level saying of the sentence "I don't just work for timepass"

Tags: phrases, expressions, phrase-requests

Basically, I want to tell my superiors that whatever work I perform, I do it to the fullest and I do it efficiently. So I want to express the sentence:

> I dont work forcibly and for time pass. I work with great care, interest and perfection.

I want this above sentence to be more high level which suits corporate environment.

Comment: You'd improve your credibility if you used correct capitalization and punctuation. :-)

Comment: Can You help me out as an example?

Comment: I think Ms. Lopez means, use apostrophes were needed (as in `don't`) and if you want to make it appealing for higher ups, try to avoid contractions. They convey an informal tone which you may not want to use at this time. http://www.businesswritingblog.com/business_writing/2006/04/dont_use_contra.html

Comment: I also mean that "I" should be capital and there should be a space between "sentence" and " in the title and there should also be a period at the end of a sentence. Putting your most conscientious attention in your writing is as important as what you actually say since "words are cheap" in that you can make all the claims about your work ethic you want.  If your written correspondence is sloppy or inaccurate, it's like you were lying about your attention to detail and perfectionism.  Best of luck!

Comment: @KristinaLopez Thank You. I understand and I do follow.

Comment: @JSanchez I went through the link you provided.It is really great and helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

**My personal work ethic is to perform my duties with great care and attention to detail, which allows me to work efficiently with minimal supervision.**

Hope that helps...

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your request, you communicate the idea that your standard of work exceeds the standard of someone who is simply working to earn money.

There are several ways to express this thought. Here are a few examples:

> I take pride in my work.
>
> I am a professional, not a day laborer.
>
> I work for more than a paycheck.